# Google sheets compare value to list, if match copy value from another adjacent cell

Tags: javascript, list, drop-down-menu, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am seeking a google sheets script to compare values entered in one cell with a set of values in a table. Then populate a corresponding cell based on the selection. I have linked a google sheets document for reference.

For example on my sheets below:
Once A2 value is selected from drop down.
1) Compare to List A27:A37
2) If match, (say A31 was a match). Then, copy value from B31 and populate that value in C2 (C2 because we inputted value in A2).

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ifK6Tc6KRrNbCMf-REIXxj4GEVlP-8gOgrqpX5_Rdlc/edit#gid=0

I would also need the option to enter a custom number without generating errors if needed. I have more notes in the google sheets document. Please if anyone could help that would be great.

Thank you!
Travis

Comment: Hello, your sreadsheet does not have any script. Please provide your code so far and what does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrayformula and vlookup to do this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(If(len(A2:A13)>0,vlookup(A2:A13,$A$27:$B$37,2,false),))
```

I also added that into your sheet so you can see the live example

[image]

If you also want to handle the custom cases - it should always find a value if you add it to your list - you would techinically want to make the vlookup range  dynamic such as `$A$27:$B` so it encapsulates any additions to the list.

You can also slightly modify your formula to handle an `iferror` so that it defaults to 0 if no value is found in the lookup, that way it wont mess up your combined price total

`=ARRAYFORMULA(iferror(If(len(A2:A13)>0,vlookup(A2:A13,$A$27:$B$37,2,false),),0))`

Comment: Aurielle, thank you for your response on this. 

Unfortunately even with the iferror feature incorporated (which defaults the field to 0), once I manually input a value there it breaks the formula. The custom value on the list may change from day to day, and updating the list each time for a custom input is not practical.

This is why I was hoping a script would work. That way if people delete the value cells the formula is not lost and manual intervention is limited.